# How to concat url in Ajax with format Laravel routes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have Ajax error code like this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "{{ route('siswa-tugas-get-soal-opsi', ['id_pilihan_ganda' => "+val.id+"]) }}",
    success: function (data) {
          console.log(data.options);
    }
});
```

If url I rewrite like: (it works)

```
url: "{{ route('siswa-tugas-get-soal-opsi', ['id_pilihan_ganda' => 3]) }}",
```

`"+val.id+"` is wrong?

Comment: You have to be more specific. What kind of error do you see? What exactly is the `val.id`? What should your desired URL looks like? What is the route for `route('siswa-tugas-get-soal-opsi' ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES,** Because you are mixing up `blade` and `javascript`.

The the `{{ route('siswa-tugas-get-soal-opsi', ['id_pilihan_ganda' => 3]) }}` this code will be render on the `Laravel Blade Engine` when page loads (in server). But here the `val.id` is a Javascript variable. It will execute after then page load.

**Solution**

You need save the `$val['id']` in PHP not is Javascript. And Try,

```
{{ route('siswa-tugas-get-soal-opsi', ['id_pilihan_ganda' => $val['id']]) }}
```

**OR**

You need write the Hard-Coded URL in Javascript. (NOT A BEST PRACTISE) like,

```
url: "your/url/route/"+val.id+"/rest/path",
```